# Как лучше реализовать структуру проекта с учетом сплэш скрина в android приложении?

Tags: java, android, kotlin

Общий вопрос ребята, сейчас объясню. Есть приложение, там при запуске запускается лого приложения. Дальше запускается основной экран это Bottom Navigation Activity, ну нижнии табы. Немного дополню вопрос: дело в том что дело не только в сплеш скрине заставке, дело в самой организации проекта, делить на 2 активити или нет, как лучше, я могу и так и так? Потому что после лога идет, например экран регистрации а потом только главное окно. Так вот у меня есть 2 варианта как это реализовать:

1. Сделать одну активити и поставить слушатель вылавливать фрагмент и при нужном экране скрывать, показывать нижние табы. Вот например для экрана с лого делать там фуллскрин.
2. Сделать 2 активити. На 1 реализовать лого и потом переход с закрытием 1 активити на 2 активити где реализовать Bottom Navigation Activity
   Я лично склоняюсь к 1 варианту, потому что я его придумал и реализовал в прошлом приложении и все равно там помоему надо будет что то отслеживать. Второй вариант я подсмотрел в другом приложении.

Comment: Почитайте про Splash Screen

Comment: Ну вот теперь с 3 вариантов выбирать :(

Comment: Если вам нужна заставка, то только splash

Comment: Да там картинка просто на экране. Я просто наверно не совсем правильно вопрос задал. Мне надо как лучше проект организовать.

Comment: Это не просто картинка, пока онга показывается, программа подгружается

Comment: Хотя я уже практически 1 вариант выбрал, так что... Может закрою. Да я почитаю Спасибо.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Правильный ответ, вообще то в зависимости от ситуации, но все же 2 вариант, тогда как 1 не всегда. В моем случае как показала практика, правильным вариантом был именно 2:
Сделать 2 активити. На 1 реализовать лого и потом переход с закрытием 1 активити на 2 активити где реализовать Bottom Navigation Activity
Почему, очень просто потому что в проекте была нижняя панель (BottomNavigationView) она конечно была в activity и когда после лога экрана  менялся фрагмент сперва вкл нижняя панель а потом все остальное, т.е. экран грузился по частям, что посчитали не красивым и я получил выговор :( А второй вариант решает эту проблему.

Answer (score 1):

Нужно брать 1-ый вариант и к нему ещё и Splash Screen подключать. Должно получиться примерно так:

1. Запускается Splash Screen (гугловая либа). Он настраивается через стили, с возможностью указать лого, фон. Можно, при желании, настроить его показ до тех пор, пока нужные данные не прогрузятся. Но лучше данные прогружать на отдельном экране, т.к. Splash Screen очень слабо кастомизируется. Однако использовать его очень стоит, т.к. на новых версиях андроида, если его не кастомизировать самостоятельно он будет системой в любом случае показываться, может некрасиво получится.
2. После Splash Screen отображать в активити фрагмент, в котором и будут загружаться нужные данные. Т.к. это просто фрагмент - на нём можно всё что угодно делать.
3. Отобразить основной фрагмент.

Так у вас будет и поддержка фичи Splash Screen на новых версиях ОС и полностью кастомизированный экран для инициализации всего что вам нужно и всего одна активити, как это и принято в современной разработке и как рекомендуется гуглом.

Comment: Спс. Ну на самом деле мне не особо важно реализация Splash Screen. Просто думал делить или не делить на активности, перед условно регистр и потом